# Writing Raster Calculator Expression?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I use ArcMap 10.3.

How do I create an expression in RasterCalculator that allows me to sum up 4 rasters (every pixel has an associated value) and the result to be 0 if any of the 4 values is 0?

For example: 1+2+0+1 must be equal to 0 but 1+2+1+1 must be equal to 5

Comment: Do 2 cell statistics raster -sum and min - and use Con after.

Comment: Have you tried using [`con()`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/conditional-evaluation-with-con.htm)?  Something like `OutRas = Con((InRas1 > 0) & (InRas2 > 0) & (InRas3 > 0) & InRas4 > 0), InRas1 + InRas2 + InRas3 + InRas4, 0)` might work if I'm understanding you (and the `con()` syntax) correct

Comment: PolyGeo i tried nothing cause idk what to do

Comment: Midavalo it is correct in fact, but its not good for what i need cause it doesent make the result 0 if one of the values is 0

Comment: This should work: `OutRas = Con((InRas1 == 0) | (InRas2 == 0) | (InRas3 == 0) | (InRas4 == 0), 0, InRas1 + InRas2 + InRas3 + InRas4)`